# DataGrip and MySql Workbench Differ on Validness of a Stored Procedure

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, datagrip

Datagrip says and runs the following procedure perfectly in mysql, however the mysql command line and workbench say that there is a syntax error in my sql. Why is this?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE addTag(n VARCHAR(255), d VARCHAR(255))
  BEGIN
    INSERT INTO Tags(name, description) VALUES
      (n, d);
  END;
```

Here's how mysql workbench shows it:

[image: mysql workbench error underline]

The action and error output is reproduced below.

CREATE PROCEDURE addTag(n VARCHAR(255), d VARCHAR(255))   BEGIN     INSERT INTO Tags(name, description) VALUES       (n, d)

Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 4

Comment: Hope it requires `DELIMITER //`. Please check this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5703441/2451726)

Comment: @Arulkumar It worked. But why is this required for mysql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you write queries in the regular SQL editor we need a way to separate statements from each other. This is done by the so-called delimiter. The default delimiter is the semicolon (which is changable).

The MySQL server however also uses the semicolon to separate statements in stored programs (stored procedures, functions, events etc.). The server can only handle one statement at a time, which is why clients have to split scripts into individual statements. This is done by using the mentioned delimiter.

Now, when you write a stored program the delimiter used by a client to split statements for the server and the delmiter within those stored programs (which are both semicolons) conflict with each other. In order to avoid that you can change the client delimiter to something else that doesn't appear in your queries (strings + comments don't count). Hence in every (My)SQL tool you will find the ability to change this delmiter to avoid this trouble.

However, there is some help in MySQL Workbench, namely by the object editors. For each object type in a database there is an object editor that is specialized to manage that object. For stored procedures/functions there is an editor that only allows the `create procedure` or `create function` block, so no (client) delimiter is needed there.

Comment: Why doesn't postgresql or sqlite(when writing triggers) mandate this?

Comment: Tbh, it surprises me that they don't require it. The same principle applies to any SQL tool that has to split statements. But maybe the default delimiter is different?