# Cannot grant privileges to a user using root on mysql

Tags: sql, mysql, database, privileges, sql-grant

I am trying to give explicit permissions to an user on mysql and im doing this (to an already created user)

```
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, CREATE, INDEX, ALTER, SHOW DATABASES, 
 CREATE TEMPORARY TABLES, LOCK TABLES, EXECUTE, CREATE VIEW, SHOW VIEW, 
 CREATE ROUTINE, ALTER ROUTINE, EVENT, TRIGGER 
ON mydatabase.* 
TO 'myuser'@'localhost' ;
```

But im getting this weird error:

> Incorrect usage of DB GRANT and GLOBAL PRIVILEGES

I tried on other schemas with other users making a GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES and seems is working. Any idea?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Some privileges only make sense when the grant references `ON *.*` as the schema.table.

The manual page https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/grant.html lists all the available privileges, and notes each for *global*, *database*, *table*, based on whether you can grant them at different levels of scope.

The `SHOW DATABASES` privilege can only be granted at the global level.

So you'll have to do it this way:

```
GRANT SHOW DATABASES 
ON *.* 
TO 'myuser'@'localhost' ;

GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, CREATE, INDEX, ALTER, 
 CREATE TEMPORARY TABLES, LOCK TABLES, EXECUTE, CREATE VIEW, SHOW VIEW, 
 CREATE ROUTINE, ALTER ROUTINE, EVENT, TRIGGER 
ON mydatabase.* 
TO 'myuser'@'localhost' ;
```

Comment: like that it runs but then when I enter with the user myuser I see no schema :s like it has no privileges

Answer (score 0):

I had the strange thing that the "root" user had the rights to grant rights, but I still had to use the user "admin" instead.

With root, I got:

```
SQL Error [1045] [28000]: Access denied for user 'root'@'%' (using password: YES)
```

It might just be the setup, but when I look it up in the GUI of DBeaver (Connection --> Users --> Grants --> View Grants), they both have all of the rights checked, and I still cannot grant rights with the "root" user.

Perhaps it helps someone with another weird db setup.

Admin:

[image]

Root:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error below:

> ERROR 1221 (HY000): Incorrect usage of DB GRANT and GLOBAL PRIVILEGES

When I gave [PROCESS](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_process) privilege on all the tables in only `apple` database (`apple.*`) to the user `john` with [GRANT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/grant.html) by login with the user `root` as shown below:

```sql
GRANT PROCESS ON apple.* TO 'john'@'localhost';
```

So, I gave `PROCESS` privilege on all the tables in all databases (`*.*`) as shown below, then I could solve the error:

```sql
GRANT PROCESS ON *.* TO 'john'@'localhost';
```

Actually, [the doc](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_show-databases) says below:

> Because any static global privilege is considered a privilege for all databases, ...

And, I gave `PROCESS` privilege on only `person` table in all databases (`*.person`) as shown below, but I got error:

```sql
GRANT PROCESS ON *.person TO 'john'@'localhost';
```

So, we need to grant [static global privilege](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/privileges-provided.html#privileges-provided-static) like `PROCESS`, [FILE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_file), [REPLICATION SLAVE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_replication-slave), etc on all the tables in all databases (`*.*`) as shown below, otherwise there is error:

```sql
GRANT [STATIC_GLOBAL_PRIVILEGES] ON *.* TO <USER>;
```