# Cannot assign permissions to a user to perform a backup in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql-grant

I am trying make an user for make backups in my database with the next privileges:

`GRANT SELECT, LOCK TABLES, SHOW VIEW, TRIGGER, EXECUTE, PROCESS ON mydatabase.* to op_backup@'localhost';`

but i recive this error:

`Incorrect usage of DB GRANT and GLOBAL PRIVILEGES`

I've looked everywhere for a solution but can't find anything, any idea what it could be?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47460670/cannot-grant-privileges-to-a-user-using-root-on-mysql

Answer (score 0):

To backup the data, `SELECT` is needed.  (Other privileges may be needed, too.)

> Incorrect usage of DB GRANT and GLOBAL PRIVILEGES

`PROCESS` should be done separately with

```
GRANT PROCESS ON *.* TO op_backup@'localhost';
```

(That exposes the `PROCESSLIST`, which include queries.  Hence, it is a potential security hole.)

Check each of the other privileges to see if any others need to be `ON *.*`.